# Python, extract raw contents from mbox file

Tags: python, email, parsing, mime, mbox

In an `mbox` file I stored some e-mails: they can also use MIME. They must be extracted *as they are* in the `mbox` file, without modifications, with a `Python3` script. I tried the following code:

```
import mailbox

for message in mailbox.mbox('mboxfile'):
    mstring = message.as_string()
    print(mstring)
```

This seems to print the e-mails' raw contents. The e-mails in the `mbox` don't always use `\r\n` for all their new lines: sometimes they have only `\n`. Anyway, in the `message.as_string()` output always `\n` is used, as specified in the [manual page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage).

The manual also states (about `as_string()`):

> Note that this method is provided as a convenience and may not be the most useful way to serialize messages in your application, especially if you are dealing with multiple messages.

I can't fully understand what this suggestion could mean. My `mbox` file obviously contains several e-mails and I would like to extract all them. Above all, I would like to obtain **exactly** the same raw e-mails stored there, without **any** modification and preserving for each line its **original** `\r\n` or `\n`, as if I were using `cat` on the `mbox` file. So:

- Is my code the correct way to do this?
- If not, which would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the contents without any modification, you can simply `print()` each `message`:

```
import mailbox

for message in mailbox.mbox('mboxfile.mbox'):
    print(message)
```

Files with the `.mbox` extension are simply long **plain text files**: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox

---

Also check out the `email` module for handling email messages as an alternative: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html